# Cannot deploy an angular2 App via Visual Studio 2015 to Azure

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure, deployment, angular

I'm new to `Azure` and `Angular2`, and i want to deploy my application to Azure via `Visual Studio 2015` since it seems to me that it is the most flexible way to do it via this IDE, my application works fine locally when using `WebStorm IDE` and `npm` task runner, the problem here is when I switched to `Visual Studio` I tried to open it as a `website project` and then when i tried to publish it to Azure this error occured `Can't find existing loaded project:C:\Users\noone\Desktop\Angular2APP\`, so then i tried to adapt that project to an empty `ASP.NET5` Project but it still a little bit blur here, do I have to put all the project files under the `wwwroot` folder ? (even the `node_module` folder ?) if that is the case , i did it but when building the project it says that it cannot build since there is a `path too long` problem in the `node_module` folder ?  Is it the right way to adapt it to an ASP.NET5 project ? is there any simpler way to deploy an Angular2 application to Azure ?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to deploy using the ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) template and then selected MVC.

One other thing I would suggest is to make a folder like "C:\Code" and use that as your starting point for your code so you don't get the path too long error message.

Comment: Thank you for your reply , I've upvoted you answer but cannot check it since i cannot verify it now , this task was deprecated. but thanks anyway.